# Generating PDF from Rails Backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 'download' button on the frontend (vue.js) that's reaching the endpoint `/reports` in my app. In the `reports_controller`, I'm scoping the data that I need and then trying to create a new PDF report. In the `report` model, I'm using the `renderanywhere` and `pdfkit` gem to try to get a PDF with the data that I'm passing through.

I'm trying to follow the documentation/example on `pdfkit` but the PDF that I'm creating is not including the data that I want (I'm only getting the h3 title and nothing else), is my `as_html` method correct? Is there something I'm missing in the template (`pdf.html.erb`)?

Is there another gem/approach that I can try?

**reports_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    send_report_pdf
  end

  private

  def report_pdf
    report = Thing.find(10)
    Report.new(report)
  end

  def send_report_pdf
    send_file report_pdf.to_pdf
  end
```

**report.rb**

```
require 'render_anywhere'

class Report
  include RenderAnywhere

  def initialize(report)
    @report = report
  end

  def to_pdf
    kit = PDFKit.new(as_html, page_size: 'A4')
    kit.to_file("#{Rails.root}/tmp/report.pdf")
  end


  private

  def as_html
    render template: "reports/pdf.html.erb",
    layout: "application",
    locals: { report: @report }
  end
end
```

**pdf.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <h1>Report Test</h1>

  <h3> <%= @report %> </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add <% byebug %> below <h1>  and try to download file or what ever and  then inside terminal when brake point  activate check the value of the @report variable?

Comment: I installed the `byebug` gem and included that line of code in my pdf.html.erb, but it's not triggering anything in my terminal. I did `rails server` and also I don't see anything in my development.log either

Comment: but how can you see then <h1> elements?

Comment: The PDF file is generated, and when I open the file, I only see the Report Test on the file.

Comment: Okay,  can you put byebug here   def initialize(report)
    byebug @report = report
  end